# Exception during processing of event of type AFTER_FILTER_EVENT

Tags: java, exception, jsf-2, spring-security

I've googled this so many times now, without any luck. Hope you are able to help me.

I have a web project that uses JSF Mojarra 2.1, Primefaces 3.1. The project uses Spring Security for handling authentication.

The project is running on Glassfish 3.1.1, so I'm using the JSF version provided.

The problem is that after I logon, I get the following Exception when the main.xhtml page should be rendered.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: WEB5001: Exception during processing of event of type AFTER_FILTER_EVENT for web module StandardEngine[glassfish-web].StandardHost[server].StandardContext[/sormAdmin2]
at com.sun.web.server.J2EEInstanceListener.handleAfterEvent(J2EEInstanceListener.java:344)
at com.sun.web.server.J2EEInstanceListener.instanceEvent(J2EEInstanceListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.util.InstanceSupport.fireInstanceEvent(InstanceSupport.java:314)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:273)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Caused by: org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationException
    at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.postInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.web.server.J2EEInstanceListener.handleAfterEvent(J2EEInstanceListener.java:339)
    ... 28 more

On the login-page:

```
$<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" styleClass="messageGrid">
                    <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" id="username"
                        required="true" label="username" />

                    <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
                    <p:password value="#{loginBean.password}" id="password"
                        required="true" label="password" feedback="false" />

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="Login"
                            action="#{loginBean.login}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:messages></h:messages>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

The LoginBean:

```
package this.is.my.mb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import this.is.my.ejb.beans.session.remote.UserRemote;
import this.is.my.ejb.ejb.vo.User;
import this.is.my.utils.EJBHandler;

import org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException;
import org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnit;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean", eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {

    //checkUser();
  }

  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private UserRemote userRemote;
  private User user;
  private String username;

  private String password;

  public LoginBean() {
    layoutCenter = new LayoutUnit();
    layoutLeft = new LayoutUnit();
    layoutRight = new LayoutUnit();
    //layoutLogin = new LayoutUnit();
  }

  public String login() {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", getUsername());  
    boolean loggedIn = true;  
    String redirectTo = "/user/main.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    try {
      EJBHandler ejbHandler2 = new EJBHandler();
      userRemote = ejbHandler2.getUserRemote();
      if(userRemote != null)
      user = userRemote.sjekkBruker(getUsername(), getPassword());        

      if(user != null) {
        System.out.println("User  != null: accessLevel: " + user.getAccessLevel());
        Authentication rfesult = new Authentication() {
          @Override
          public String getName() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return username;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean isAuthenticated() {
            return true;
          }

          @Override
          public Object getPrincipal() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
          }

          @Override
          public Object getDetails() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
          }

          @Override
          public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            GrantedAuthority ga = new GrantedAuthority() {
              private static final long serialVersionUID  = 1132123132132L;

              @Override
              public String getAuthority() {
                return "ROLE_USER";
              }
            };          

            GrantedAuthority g2a = new GrantedAuthority() {
              private static final long serialVersionUID  = 1132123132132L;

              @Override
              public String getAuthority() {
                return "ROLE_STATS";
              }
            };

            GrantedAuthority g3a = new GrantedAuthority() {
              private static final long serialVersionUID  = 1132123132132L;

              @Override
              public String getAuthority() {
                return "ROLE_ADMIN";
              }
            };

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            if(user.getAccessLevel() == 3 || user.getAccessLevel() == 1) {
              list.add(ga);
            }
            if(user.getAccessLevel() == 2 || user.getAccessLevel() == 1) {
              list.add(g2a);
            }
            if(user.getAccessLevel() == 1) {
              list.add(g3a);
            }
            return list;
          }

          @Override
          public Object getCredentials() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
          }

          @Override
          public void setAuthenticated(boolean arg0) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
          }

        };
        checkUser();
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(rfesult);

        if(user.getAccessLevel() == 2) { // user only has access to statistics
          redirectTo = "/stats/getstats.jsf?faces-redirect=true";   
        }
        if(user.getAccessLevel() < 1) {
          redirectTo = "/login/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
          msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login failed", "Wrong username and/or password");
          loggedIn = false;
        }
      } else {
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login failed", "Wrong username and/or password");
        loggedIn = false;
        redirectTo = null;
        System.out.println("User  == null");
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    if(context != null)
    context.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    System.out.println(redirectTo);
    return redirectTo;
  }

  public User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }


  public String getUsername() {
    checkUser();
    return username;}}
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>  

  <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- for EL 2.2-->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>300</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>redmond</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: The stacktrace is incomplete. You've only shown the outermost exception while the answer is in the innermost exception (the bottommost one in the entire stacktrace). Please edit your question to include the entire stacktrace.

Comment: This is the only stacktrace I can find in the Glassfish logs...
Caused by: org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationException
 at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.postInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:190)
 at com.sun.web.server.J2EEInstanceListener.handleAfterEvent(J2EEInstanceListener.java:339)
 ... 28 more
28 more... But I can't reach them..

Comment: Was this problem ever solved?  I am seeing a very similar error, intermittently.  I had already implemented the solution as suggested by @Jonathan and am still seeing this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help... I abandoned this approach and configured ldap/ActiveDirectory in security-context.xml (org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider). Hope you find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and the cause was that the user detail or info I passed to my returned token (an instance of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) did not implement Spring Security's UserDetails (or extend User) .

**My solution was:**

1) My custom authentication provider:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
...
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        ...
        MyUserLoginDetails loginUser = new MyUserLoginDetails(username,
            password, isActive, true, true, true, authorities, userId);
        ...
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginUser, null, authorities);
    }
}
```

2) My user login class extending `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`:

```
public class MyUserLoginDetails extends User {

    /**
     * Auto-generated serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7045871751446202245L;

    private Long userId;

    public MyUserLoginDetails(String username, String password,
            boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, Long userId) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```